# Security of the OIDC login page with authorization_code flow

Tags: security, openid-connect, openid-provider

When we use the authorization code flow in the OIDC, I go to /authorization and then it redirect me to the OIDC provider's login page. On this login page there is something like redirectUrl query string, which contains link to /authorization with parameters like client_id, state, code_challenge etc. When I'm writing OIDC server, should I worry about this, that these parameters can be changed while user is on login page (e.g. by a malicious extension in the browser)? Maybe should I save these parameters in httponly, secure cookie after GET request on login page?

Comment: You're not sharing any secret on that request, auth code + pkce flow is used in non-confidential clients. The configuration sitting on your identity server (redirect_uri in particular) will prevent any other client from using those parameters as only your application (sitting in the redirect_uri) will be able to receive the response code. Try changing the paremeters and watch it fail

Comment: Yes, but if the user has, for example, a malicious extension installed in the browser, it can change the query parameters and log the user into another client. In this way, it can obtain, for example user's e-mail. Should I somehow protect the user from something like this?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to protect them from their already compromised machine? Have you been sucessfull into doing that? I think that the nonce wont match and the flow wont work

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. But suppose all parameters are changed to match another client and that other client is the attacker's client, so the attacker doesn't check state, nonce etc. Is there any way to prevent this user from attack?

Comment: You're preventing that by setting up the clients configuration in your identity server. The attacked would have to gain access to your identity server configuration to set up his client there.

Comment: What if my server was something like Google Identity so that everyone could create their own client there? I understand that then it's impossible to avoid such an attack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I'm writing OIDC server, should I worry about this, that these parameters can be changed while
> user is on login page (e.g. by a malicious extension in the browser)? Maybe should I save these
> parameters in httponly, secure cookie after GET request on login page?

hiding `/authorize` parameters beyond a plain sight of the user does not protect them from man-in-the-browser[1] attacker, where he/she would be able to access those data anyway.

OIDC specification allows to pass requests via JWT tokens which can optionaly be signed or even encrypted which should provide extra level of security in considered cases [2, 3].

As IDP you might defend you users with incorporating out-of-band transaction verification [1], where if user is aware about requested login transactions, might infere that extra transaction is being made on his/her behaf or confirming message is missing in the authentication flow.

Also IDP instance should protects itself from registering services from unauthorized parties in order to prevent attackers from creating phishing sites, pretending being a legitimate service using legitimate IDP. The `/authorize` request contains service credentials (client id, client secret) which must be correctly verified by the IDP.

For more practical elaboration I'd recommend pentesterlab.com where Authentication/Authorization badge exercise series will allow you to learn and practice several attacks on OAuth and OIDC protocols and
implementations.

- [1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-browser
- [2] https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#JWTRequests
- [3] https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#RequestDisclosure
- [4] https://pentesterlab.com/badges/auth